# how to run exe from web app

Tags: java

I need to  copy data to card writer attached to local pc from the web app(run card writer exe with parameters with java runtime). What's the best way to implement such functionality? Java applet, web service or something else?

Comment: Thanks I planned to go for signed applet although href looks so simple solution. Any way to bypass open save box and execute without opening this dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a signed Java applet to download and launch the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a client side solution so don't look into server technologies.
I know that a **signed** Java applet will suffice (Signed makes it run out of the security sandbox).
Java Script won't allow you.
Maybe Silverlight and Flash can help but they are more restricted than a signed Java applet.
You can allways use a simple `<a href="your.exe"/>` and let the user select open in the open or save dialog that will popup in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing else would be my pick. I'd provide a download to the user from the web page, and a wee application and installer for the cardwriter. Otherwise it's just a mass of security stumbling blocks and issues.